# Data Transfer from one table to other table using WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am trying copy data from one table to another identical table using data service concept in wso2 ei.
The source table is having 99997 records, so I am pulling data with limit like [select * from table between 1 to 750] but the resultset takes around 3 mins of time. If I continue with this logic the whole copying would take hours, which is not fruitful.
Can anyone help how can this be achieved using WSO2 EI

Answer (score 1):

Since this is db related requirement, you don’t need to use a EI. Best method would be to take a DB dump and restore it in the second database.

Comment: Hi, It has to be done on daily basis at Integration platform.

Comment: You can write a stored procedure to copy the data. The stored procedure can then be executed by the the data service 

http://soatutorials.blogspot.com/2013/09/writing-data-service-to-execute-stored.html

Comment: yes I have written stored procedure to fetch/insert the data. But while fetching it takes more than 3 mins to pull around 750 rows from database which is too much time if I want to process 1lakh of data.